# Azure Logic Apps and Custom Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am relatively new to Logic Apps and still learning. I have a question about the direction I should take to solve the following problem.
Let's say I need to create a server-side component that needs to connect to 3rd party data provider via the socket. My company is very young, small, and fully on the cloud. My immediate thought on how to accomplish this is to start and maintain a server on the Azure cloud - Windows or Unix. However, this will add additional monthly costs.
here goes my question - is there something in Azure I can use to start my process (C#, Python, or Java) and maintain a connection to the third-party program via sockets without creating and maintaining (and paying) for the server on the cloud?

Again I am interested in an Azure-based solution something around Logic App (unless there is something else out there)

Comment: Can you be more specific about this socket connection requirement? Why does the connection need to be persisted? Why can’t you just connect, do your thing and disconnect?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for asking. Bloomberg for example has a service that you connect to via socket protocol. You send to Bloomberg list of stocks and Bloomberg starts streaming real time prices to you. You store prices into your database for future analysis.

Comment: What you want to do requires persisted compute and compute costs money in any cloud service. My suggestion would be to look at using a container service but again, that will cost. Does Bloomberg also offer a pub/sub service where they can send data to a webhook? That would be easier and cheaper to implement.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought and that is how I dealt with it in the past working with servers. Will look into WebHooks. Also, there is something on Azure Cloud called Durable functions. Maybe something there to explore...  --thanks!

Comment: A function app that runs on a dedicated app service has unlimited run time as well, using durable functions would be overkill I’d think.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin that you can use webhook if Bloomberg offers pub/sub service and about Functions you can use Function app with Dedicated App service plan while creating it:

[image]

Or Inside Azure Functions you can code related to 3rd Party and you can use timer trigger or http trigger. If you want to send mails or something else you can use logic apps for it.